# How do I set foreign_keys on a has_many: :through association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, has-many-through

I have 2 tables, `Item` and `ItemBelonging`. I'm trying to create tree relationships between `items`. For every descendant of an `item` I create a `item_belonging` to join the `item` and the descendent `item`.

```
Item {
  id:,
  ...
}

ItemBelonging {
  id:,
  item_id:,
  descendant_id:,
  ...
}
```

I am able to successfully call `item.descendants` to receive all descendants of an item. I have set up the relationships like this:

```
class ItemBelonging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :descendant, :class_name => 'Item'
  ...
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :descendants, :through => :item_belongings, :source => :descendant
  ...
end
```

The problem is that I would like to be able to call `item.ancestors` to get all ancestors of an item using the same `ItemBelonging` relationship. I am able to do this like so:

```
  def ancestors
    Item.joins(:item_belongings).where("item_belongings.descendant_id = ?", id)
  end
```

But how do I create this relationship using has_many/belongs_to? This does not work:

```
class ItemBelonging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :descendant, :class_name => 'Item'
  belongs_to :ancestor, :class_name => 'Item', :foreign_key => :item_id
  ...
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :descendants, :through => :item_belongings, :source => :descendant
  has_many :ancestors, :through => :item_belongings, :source => :ancestor, :foreign_key => :descendant_id
  ...
end
```

My end goal is to be able to call `Item.includes(:descendants)` and `Item.includes(:ancestors)`. How do I get the `ancestors` relationship working?

Answer (score 1):

With [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem you can easily use such DSL

```rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_ancestry
end
```

And then create few records

```rb
parent = Item.create
first_child = Item.create(parent: parent)
second_child = Item.create(parent: parent)
first_child_child = Item.create(parent: first_child)
```

And use such methods out of box

```
parent.children # => [first_child, second_child]
parent.descendants # => [first_child, second_child, first_child_child]
first_child.siblings # => [first_child, second_child]
first_child.subtree # => [first_child, first_child_child]
first_child_child.parent # => first_child
first_child_child.root # => parent
first_child_child.ancestors # => [parent, first_child]
first_child_child.path # => [parent, first_child, first_child_child]
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how I can set up ancestors through my existing table relationships without the ancestry gem?